# Can Android 4.03 send file/image batches?

Tags: file-transfer

I'm looking around on the play store for an app that would allow me to select a set of images to send via smail.  Because there's a 3 mb limit per e-mail (probably imposed by my provider), I was hoping a developer was intelligent enough to create something that perhaps used multiple smails (or somehow otherwise hacked things).  Batch upload/download so I can send a bunch of pictures to my friends without hassle, basically, without logging into things.  If there's an easy way to do this, please let me know?

Comment: smail? And if you want to send files without very limited limits, you could try free cloud based sharing such as DropBox.

Comment: Try zipping the files, here's a list of some apps that do it: http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-apps-zip-rar-filex-101621/    Blackmoon File Browser is recommended on the link for zipping and sending images: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackmoonit.android.FileBrowser

Comment: Zip is nice, I suppose, because it cuts out the middleman (like cloud).  Doesn't require the other user to connect to a site.  I'm not sure that cloud has bulk downloading, either.  Combined with .zip/.rar, it could represent a solution, though.  For straight SMS, creating an archive only slightly reduces the size of the files and creates an extra step along the way towards uploading.  It probably takes roughly the same amount of time to select 5-10 files for upload from the mail view as it takes to select 7-12 for zip and click archive....  I'll have to fiddle around with archives to be sure.

Comment: ZIP won't do much help if the limit is *size* instead of *count*: JPeg (which is used for photos) already uses compression, so `.jpg` images won't get much smaller with a `.zip`. Could you please make clear what you mean by `smail`? From the context I take it you want to send the files by e-mail -- is that correct?